# How to convert time (hh:mm) to decimal form with momentjs

Tags: momentjs

what is the best way to convert Hours  Minutes to Decimal Time with momentjs

let say i have 1:30 min and i want to have 1.5 after the conversion

here is what i have tried

```
console.log(travelTime().split(':')[0]);   return 1
console.log(travelTime().split(':')[1]);   return 30  then / 30
```

where travelTime() == "1:30"

Comment: Why would it be 1.75? 40 minutes is two thirds of an hour, not three quarters. Did you mean 1:45?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like what you want is `moment.duration(durationAsString)` to parse your duration and `.asHours()` to format as decimal.

`moment.duration('1:30').asHours();` will return `1.5`.

For more information, see Moment's documentation section on durations: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: But how do you do the opposite of that noww?

Comment: You can use `moment.duration(1.5, 'hours')` to get it back to a moment duration. Formatting that as `1:30` though isn't something moment appears to be able to do out of the box. You could do `duration.hours()` and `duration.minutes()` to reconstruct it manually, or you could use `duration.humanize()` for a more human-friendly format than 1:30.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using this crazy function.
`function hourIndexToTime(num) {
      return ('0' + Math.floor(num) % 24).slice(-2) + ':' + ((num % 1)*60 + '0').slice(0, 2);
  }`

Comment: Adding on to pualjz's comment for clarification...in this example of 1.5 hours, duration.hours() will equal 1 and duration.minutes() will be 30. It was not clear that hours and minutes are split out already. Exactly what I needed.